# Append [i] named items

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, I have an input field which is the value for a loop.

1. The user enters the desired value in the first field.
2. The user clicks button/badge (click me to add bullet) to append to a modal.
3. The modal appears with the number of Bullets based on the input value in the field.

For example, if the input is `3` the modal will have 3 `text` boxes with placeholders listed as `Bullet1`, `Bullet2`, and  `Bullet3`.

What I would like to have is the user input text in the text boxes and then this information be appended within another modal.
For example, If I typed in `Bullet1`: AA, `Bullet2`: BB, and `Bullet3`: CC, it should append:

```html
<li>AA</li><li>BB</li><li>CC</li>
```

with my current code, it appends

```html
<li>CC</li><li>CC</li><li>CC</li>
```

This is likely my for loop, but i have tried a few things and still haven't got it to work. see snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bulletAddr').click(function() {
    $('#codeAddBullet').append(escape("<ul>"));

    function escape(value) {
      return value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < valueField.value; i++) {
      var varBullet = "Bullet"
      var varI = i + 1
      var varBR = "<br>"
      var bulletI = varBullet + varI

      var varBulletField = "bulletField"
      var bulletFieldI = varBulletField + bulletI

      $('#outPut').append(" <input type='text' id='" + bulletFieldI + "' placeholder=" + bulletI + ">" + varBR)
    }

    $('#addTheseBullets').click(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < valueField.value; i++) {
        var varBulletFieldN = "#bulletField"
        var bulletFieldI = varBulletFieldN + bulletI
        var bulletValue = $(bulletFieldI).val()
        $('#codeAddBullet').append(escape("<li>") + bulletValue + escape("</li>"))

        function escape(value) {
          return value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.bsFireBrick {
    background-color: firebrick;
    border-color: black;
    color:white;
    border-color: #46b8da;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS  & JS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='valueField' placeholder="Enter # of Bullets to Add"> <span class="badge badge-info" id="bulletAddr" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Click me to add bullet</span>
<br>
<span class="bsFireBrick" id="clickForCode" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">#3 Click for Raw Code</span>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

<!-- Modal 2-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Bullet Adder</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id='outPut'>
        </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addTheseBullets">Add All Bullets </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Code Below</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p> &ltHTML&gt <br> &ltHEAD&gt <br> &ltTITLE&gt <span id="codeTitleHere">  </span> &lt/TITLE&gt <br> &ltSTYLE&gt <br> &lt/STYLE&gt
            <br> &ltBODY&gt <br> SUMMARY <br> HEADING <br> <span id="codeAddBullet"> </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

think you can help me out ?

Comment: Place your escape function inside `$(document).ready(function() {` so that you don't have to define it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found many errors in your code so I tried to fix them. Here is what I did:

1. I cleaned the code, the `escape()` method is global so it must be outside of the `$(document).ready()` call.
2. I defined constants like the `baseName`, `baseId`, and `varBR`;
3. I defined two variables that will hold the size and the id of the element. This will be useful when I need to reset that variable.
4. In the `$('#bulletAddr').click()` callback I defined `id` and `placeholder` the `id` will hold the id of the element that will be used in the 3rd modal. While the `placeholder` is the name shown in the `text` box.
5. In the `$('#addTheseBullets').click()` callback I defined an `id` and is `bulletValue`. As you can see the this `id` is the same as the id defined in the point number 4. This will get the correct value as you can see in the snippet.
6. Finally, I added a `$('#myModal2 .close').click()` and `$('#clickForCode').click()` to close the modal and open the last modal.

Check the code here:

```js
const baseName = 'Bullet';
const baseId = 'bullet_field_';
const varBR = '<br>';

let size;
let sizeField;

function escape(value) {
  return value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  sizeField = $('#valueField');
  $('#bulletAddr').click(function() {
    size = sizeField.val();
    $('#codeAddBullet').append(escape("<ul>"));
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      let index = i + 1;
      let id = baseId + index;
      let placeholder = baseName + (i + 1);
      $('#outPut').append('<input type="text" id="' + id + '" placeholder="' + placeholder + '">' + varBR);
    }

    $('#addTheseBullets').click(function() {
      size = sizeField.val();
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let index = i + 1;
        let id = baseId + index;
        let bulletValue = $('#' + id).val();
        $('#codeAddBullet').append(escape('<li>') + bulletValue + escape('</li>'));
      }
      $('#myModal2 .close').click();
      $('#myModal').modal();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bsFireBrick {
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#myModal {
  overflow: auto; !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS  & JS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' id='valueField' placeholder="Enter # of Bullets to Add">
<span class="badge badge-info" id="bulletAddr" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Click me to add bullet</span>
<br>
<span class="bsFireBrick" id="clickForCode" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">#3 Click for Raw Code</span>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->


<!-- Modal 2-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Bullet Adder</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id='outPut'></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addTheseBullets">Add All Bullets </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Code Below</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p> &ltHTML&gt <br> &ltHEAD&gt <br> &ltTITLE&gt <span id="codeTitleHere">  </span> &lt/TITLE&gt <br> &ltSTYLE&gt <br> &lt/STYLE&gt
            <br> &ltBODY&gt <br> SUMMARY <br> HEADING <br> <span id="codeAddBullet"> </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works beautifully, thank you for the clean up, i still learning, code is supurb!!

Answer (score 0):

Note the `bulletI` variable, you should also have

```
var bulletI = varBullet + varI
```

in your last for loop, i.e. the one inside `$('#addTheseBullets').click(function() {`.

Your problem is that, the bulletI is the OLD value in the upper loop.